# Webpack Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: angular, gulp, webpack

[image: Print Screen]

Chrome dev tools is showing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import after
deploying my web app with webpack. It is happening in app.blundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js too. As an example line import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser. at:

app.blundle.js

```
webpackJsonp([0],[
/* 0 */
/*!*****************************!*\
  !*** ./angular2App/boot.ts ***!
  \*****************************/
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    import { AppModule }              from './app/app.module';

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);


/***/ }
]);
//# sourceMappingURL=app.bundle.js.map
```

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules\/(?!(@angular\/common\/src\/facade\/.+))|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
    ...
```

Gulpfile

```
gulp.task('app', ['app_clean'], function (cb) {
    pump([
        gulp.src(srcPaths.app),
        gp_sourcemaps.init(),
        gp_typescript(require('./tsconfig.json').compilerOptions),
        gp_uglify({mangle:false}).on('error', gutil.log),
        gp_sourcemaps.write('/'),
        gulp.dest(destPaths.app)
    ],
    cb
    );
});

// Delete wwwroot/app contents
gulp.task('app_clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(destPaths.app + "*", { read: false })
    .pipe(gp_clean({ force: true }));
});

// Delete wwwroot/app contents
gulp.task('app_clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(destPaths.app + "*", { read: false })
    .pipe(gp_clean({ force: true }));
});

gulp.task('webpack', function (done) {
    webpack(config).run(onBuild(done));
});

function onBuild(done) {
    return function (err, stats) {
        if (err) {
            gutil.log('Error', err);
            if (done) {
                done();
            }
        }
        else {
            Object.keys(stats.compilation.assets).forEach(function (key) {
                gutil.log('(+)Webpack:'+key);
            });
            gutil.log('(-)Webpack: '+stats.compilation.name);
            if (done) {
                done();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Watch specified files and define what to do upon file changes
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    //gulp.watch([srcPaths.app, srcPaths.js], ['app', 'js']);
    gulp.watch([srcPaths.app, srcPaths.js], ['app', 'webpack']);
});

// Define the default task so it will launch all other tasks
//gulp.task('default', ['app', 'js', 'watch']);  
gulp.task('default', ['app', 'webpack', 'watch']);
```

Gulp will run webpack and also deploy app code too. For debugging purposes. I read your additional information and webpack has a plugin to minify JS too. My question is am I in the correct way? Or webpack can also deploy app code too for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using babel for compiling. Angular2 is written in typescript. You need to use ts-loader or awesome-typescript-loader for bundle your application.
in your webpack.config

```
{ test: /\.ts$/, 
  loaders: ["awesome-typescript-loader"]
}
```

Note:- browser don't understand typescript and it's syntax. you need to compile it to JavaScript before you can deliver it to browser. You also need some more configuration for make it work. you need a tsconfig.json to tell webpack how to compile your ts modules.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }
}
```

[Readmore about it](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

Comment: Thank you for the awesome-typescript-loader tip, fixed the errors. I am also using Gulp to deploy app into wwwroot folder. After fixing these errors, the app got stucked loading... it does not show any issue and it is not loading. About your note, I am using gulp too for these. Will update my question with more information. Any thoughts?

Comment: it's vbery hard to tell what it can be. i would suggest you ask new question or update it for more help.